# Using an extension's class from inside my controller (yii2 application)

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to use a method from inside my controller.

This works inside my "view"

```
use aweber\aweber\aweber_api;

$consumerKey    = "XXXX";
$consumerSecret = "XXXXX";
$aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
```

but it doesn't work in my controller.

I get the error

```
Class 'app\controllers\AWeberAPI' not found
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I think you extracted AWeber-API-PHP-Library to the path aweber\aweber\aweber_api. The directory structure could be

```
$ ls aweber\aweber\aweber_api

aweber.php
aweber_api.php
....
```

If you autoloading classes with composer, AWeberAPI is in root namespace

```
use \AWeberAPI;
$aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
```

If you are not autoloading with composer

```
require_once('aweber_api/aweber_api.php');
$aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the extensione related are in vendor  namespace ..

try with

```
use vendor\aweber\aweber_api;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. The name of the php file usually is the same name of the class. So your code should be:

```
use aweber\aweber\AWeberAPI;
```

If it isn't, you can try:

```
use aweber\aweber\aweber_api as AWeberAPI;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments here. To fix it I actually moved this functionality into my "view" instead of having it in my controller and it worked.

I wasn't able to test the responses here, so if anyone else if facing the same issues, I'd recommend trying some of these answers.